# Разработка игр в Крыму

Tags: разработка-игр, google-play, admob, монетизация

**Вступление**

Доброго времени суток! Сам по себе имею 2-х летний опыт в геймдеве в роли геймдизайнера, работал в студии. Рассказывал свои впечатления и опыт одному из знакомых (разработчик), и однажды он предложил создать свою игру. Делать решили под Android (дешевле и проще). Взяв на себя весь груз ответственности (дабы не отвлекать от дела дева) изучаю статьи и различную документацию. 
До этого никогда не имел дел с разработкой под Android, но, если я всё правильно понял, то при регистрации ничего серьёзного быть не может, кроме как оплаты в $25... В общем, если что-то интересного подскажете - буду рад. Ну а теперь к делу.

**Суть**

Интересует вот какой момент. Может ли где-то выступить препятствием, что мы из Крыма? Понятное дело, что даже то SDK для компиляции мы качали через VPN, но будут ли ещё серьёзные проблемы? Ведь мы хотим регистрироваться в AdMob, а так же Appodeal, хочется что-то вывести и попробовать что-то серьёзное. Какие ещё подводные камни могут ждать жителей Крыма?

Спасибо!

Comment: Боюсь, Ваш вопрос заминусуют как не соответствующий тематике сайта...

Comment: Хм, но ведь это ресурс для вопросов касательно разработки? Если это так, то у меня прямой вопрос. Ведь ресурсов где можно узнать что-то подобное практически нет.

Comment: Ресурс по большей части касается _процесса разработки_, кода, технологий и т.п. Но лично я, если что, совсем не против таких вопросов :)

Comment: Вопрос слишком общий, удалить даже могут. Тут решают конкретные проблемы, а это слишком размыто, конкретизируйте проблему, например: при публикации в Х могут ли забанить (хотя это скорее правовой, чем технический вопрос, конечно)?

Comment: Я с вами согласен, но все же, мой вопрос напрямую из области разработки, или как называют - внутренняя кухня :), которую к сожалению не все знают.

Comment: Если задавать более точный вопрос, придется делать это много раз, а я не хочу спамить.

Comment: Лучше 8 узких вопросов, чем один общий.

Comment: Хороший вопрос, самому интересно стало. Заведите "партнера" в "лицензионной" России и проводите все юридически чувствительные операции через этого посредника, например.

Answer (score 2):

По закону Гугл не имеет право с Вами работать, если "спалитесь" - обязан заблокировать

> В связи с распоряжением правительства США от 19 декабря 2014 года, компании, работающие на территории США, не имеют права сотрудничать с компаниями/физ лицами из Крыма.
>   Сегодня некоторые фрилансеры из Крыма получили письма от Upwork(oDesk, Elance) следующего содержания:

источник: http://jff.name/odesk-block-crimea/

Речь в вопросе не про фриланс, но проблема очень схожая.

Возможно, лучше не светить нигде в интернете, что ваш гугл плей аккаунт связан с Крымом

Comment: То есть, теоретически, если не светить Крымом, то все будет хорошо?

Comment: Ну, если IP тоже как-то маскировать...

Comment: Не для рекламы, но я пользуюсь CyberGhost и она хорошо делает все.

А еще в догонку вопрос. А проблем с выводом не должно быть?

Comment: @D1zg не для рекламы, но можно на сайте jff.name почитать про то, как на карту Payoneer деньги выводят,как доказать, что из России. Но я не знаю, насколько применим тот способ к Гугл Плею.

Comment: @Schullz спасибо!